# Node-js Tedious connection with Oracle DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, oracle, tedious

I need to create a connection to an Oracle database with the Tedious library in node js.
When i run the file this is what it return ' ConnectionError: Connection lost - socket hang up ',
I don't know if this is useful information but I noticed that the SID parameter is set in the settings. Let me know if you need anything else. Thank you all.

This is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Connection = require('tedious').Connection;


let credsDb = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'creds_db_cmo.json')).toString());

var config = {
    server: credsDb.server,
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: credsDb.user,
            password: credsDb.password
        }
    },
    options: {
        port: 1521,
        encrypt: false,
        database: credsDb.database,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
    }
}

var connectionDB = new Connection(config);
connectionDB.on('connect', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('DB Connected');
    }
});

connectionDB.connect();
```

the creds_db_cmo.json is:

{
"user" : "user",
"password": "password",
"server": "server",
"database": "database"
}

Comment: isn't tedious for SQL Server https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious ? You should be using  node-oracledb

Comment: with oracledb i have a different issue. 
Error: NJS-518: cannot connect to Oracle Database. Service "prct" is not registered with the listener at host 10.0.0.35 port 1521. (CONNECTION_ID=5Op
L5N2JLAmi6jazdi++2Q==)
There is a problem with the SID configuration?

Comment: @Gexs NJS-518 means your connection string is wrong, specifically the service name. Or maybe the DB wasn't fully started when you tried to connect. I don't know what connection string you are using so search for similar issues and open a new question if you still have difficulties.  Note that Service Names and SIDs are different.  You will want to use a service name in your connect string.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks, I found the right string and solved it using oracledb.